# Flash Plugin Install - Dependency Problem

Tags: apt, flash, dependencies, plugins

Today I get a new fresh copy of my Ubuntu 12.04 32Bit. I install ubuntu-restricted-extras from terminal and all was okey. But when I try to open youtube, it says that I need to install flash plugin.

I thought the flash plugin would automatically install with restricted extras. Next I tried to do with "sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer", but come up with following messages.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 flashplugin-installer : Depends: libnss3-1d but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libnspr4-0d but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Anyone could please help me how can I overcome this problem.

Comment: Kindly run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Did it, still have the same problem @KunalSangwan

Comment: Install `libnss3-1d` and `libnspr4-0d` with `apt-get` and see what error, if any, it gives you

Comment: @user223475 have a look on my answer below. hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

How abt you manually install flash player for linux from tar.gz file. Go to adobe flash player site and download the `tar.gz` [image: Adobe Flash Player Site from where you can download tar.gz]

Since mine is 64 bit architecture, it shows 64 bit, For you have to download 32 bit. I suppose the contents are downloaded in `Downloads` folder. Right click and extract the contents. In the extracted folder, check there be a file `libflashplayer.so`. Type `sudo nautilus` in your terminal and give the password. This will open a nautilus file manager with root access. Go to `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins` Copy and paste the `libflashplayer.so` from Downloads directory to here. Close nautilus. Close terminal. Open Firefox, go to Plugins, `Tools->Addons->Plugins`, If it shows Shockwave Flash that means you have successfully installed Flash, Head on to Youtube.com and Enjoy. Hope it helps.